# How to use PyFPDF data as a PDF without having to export (output) it as a PDF?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pyfpdf

I am using PyFPDF to create custom PDF documents automatically when a user registers using my custom-built Django application. The PDFs contain information about that persons registration. For each person that registers, I **do not** want to save their pdf as a separate pdf - I want to mail their PDF immediately after I have formatted it.

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(file_path, 0, 0, 210)
pdf.set_text_color(1, 164, 206)
pdf.set_font("helvetica", size=26)
pdf.ln(142)
pdf.cell(0, 0, txt=name, ln=4, align="C")
```

This is what I have currently to format the PDF, where `name` is a value retrieved from each individual user's registration.

This is what comes immediately after, and what I want to replace:

```
val = uuid.uuid4().hex
pdf.output(val+".pdf")
```

Right now, I am exporting each PDF with a unique filename, and then sending it to each user's email.

What I would prefer is to use the `pdf` variable directly when sending each email, as below:

```
finalEmail = EmailMessage(
    subject,
    plain_message,
    from_email,
    [email]
)
finalEmail.attach("Registration.pdf", pdf)
finalEmail.send()
```

However, Django does not accept this as a valid attachment type, as it is a FPDF variable still.

> expected bytes-like object, not FPDF

How would I go about this?

Comment: if  export can work with file-like object then you can use `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` to create file in memory, write in this file and later read from this file.

Comment: [documentation](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html) shows second parameter in `output()` which let you get it as bytes string.

Comment: @furas if I output it as bytes string, where is that stored? In the PDF variable itself?

Comment: I would expect `content = pdf.output(val+".pdf", 'S')`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thankyou. Do you want to put it as the answer so I can upvote / mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [documentation](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html) you can see parameter `S` which gives it as bytes string

```
content = pdf.output(val+".pdf", 'S')
```

and now you can use `content` to create attachement in email.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me: `content = BytesIO(bytes(pdf.output(dest = 'S'), encoding='latin1'))`

Answer (score 0):

#### I modify answer from IX8 like this:

`content = io.BytesIO(bytes(pdf.output(dest = 'S'), encoding='latin1'))`
`with open("Registration.pdf", "wb") as temp_file:`
    `temp_file.write(content.getvalue())`
now you can use Registration.pdf where you want

Answer (score 0):

[`fpdf2`](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/) is the maintained alternative to the old fpdf.

Install it via

```
pip install fpdf2
```

There it works like this:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("helvetica", "B", 16)
pdf.cell(40, 10, "Hello World!")
byte_string = pdf.output()
stream BytesIO(byte_string)
```

[output](https://py-pdf.github.io/fpdf2/fpdf/fpdf.html#fpdf.fpdf.FPDF.output) still has a `dest` parameter, but it is deprecated